# Saving files to specific localization and showing them as items in ListBox [WPF]

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, listbox, save

I'm writing a notepad application similar to OneNote, Evernote or Apple Notes - just for exercise - and I want to make a ListBox which will store list of saved notes. When user clicks the item (note), the text will open in RichTextBox.

I've been thinking about using .xml files, which will store title of the note, date when note was created and localization of the file. The *.rtf files, which will be actual note file, needs to be saved in specific location. ListBox needs to be updated if there were any saved notes/files within specific location.

---

Here's my shortened XAML code:

```xml
<Window x:Class="StudyNotes.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StudyNotes"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="StudyNotes" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Icon="app_icons/appicon2.ico">
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" Executed="Save_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="225" MinWidth="180" MaxWidth="600"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="#FFDDEFFF" BorderBrush="#FFADBECD" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3"/>
    <ListBox Margin="10,86,10,10.5"/>
    <Button x:Name="NewNoteButton" Margin="0,10,35,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Focusable="False" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Click="NewNoteButton_Click">
        <Image Source="/icons/page_add.png" Stretch="None"></Image>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="DeleteNoteButton" Margin="0,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Focusable="False" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
        <Image Source="/icons/page_delete.png" Stretch="None"></Image>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Full XAML code:
https://pastebin.com/JbPq2HXT

Here's my shortened C# code:

```cs
private void Save_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "Rich Text Format (*.rtf)|*.rtf";
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(saveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create);
            TextRange range = new TextRange(MainTextEditor.Document.ContentStart, MainTextEditor.Document.ContentEnd);
            range.Save(fileStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
        }
    }

    private void NewNoteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument();
        MainTextEditor.Document = document;
        TitleBox.Text = "";
    }
```

Full C# code:
https://pastebin.com/vKhJBAtd

---

Here's my application and Apple Notes as an idea: [image: My app and Apple Notes as example]

---

What I need do to in order to make ListBox to be similar in functioning like Apple Notes or Evernote or something like that?

Comment: localization in this post sounds like a misspelling of location. Do you really mean localization?

Comment: @emoacht Yes, I mean location, sorry for my misspelling. I didn’t know it has different meaning.

Comment: Filesystem watcher https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2 allows you to monitor a folder for file changes.